# Template validation error when launching cloud formation stack for a facebook application

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to host a facebook app on AWS. 
As explained in http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1044/, I clicked launch stack and navigated to cloud formation stack and pointed out to http://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-facebook/SampleFacebookPHP.template as provided in the article.

When I click next I am facing the error "Template validation error: Template error: Paramater 'FacebookAppId' AllowedPattern must be on a parameter of type String". I checked the template and found "Number" data type is mentioned for facebookAppId, I don't understand why it is expecting a string.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: It would help to know what value you put in the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a validator such as this to validate your CloudFormation Template

http://cloudformation-validation.com